# Converting AVB17221EntityDiscoveryDelegate protocol from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working with the AudioVideoBridging framework. I am also coding my app in Swift.
I am very new to all of this.

I looked up some other protocol conversions and followed the same format but I am get a compiler error.

Here is the objective c protocol

```
- (void)didAddRemoteEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)newEntity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didRemoveRemoteEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)oldEntity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didRediscoverRemoteEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)entity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didUpdateRemoteEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)entity changedProperties:(AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged)changedProperties on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didAddLocalEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)newEntity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didRemoveLocalEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)oldEntity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didRediscoverLocalEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)entity on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
- (void)didUpdateLocalEntity:(AVB17221Entity *)entity changedProperties:(AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged)changedProperties on17221EntityDiscovery:(AVB17221EntityDiscovery *)entityDiscovery;
```

Here is my conversion:

```
func didAddRemoteEntity (newEntity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didRemoveRemoteEntity (oldEntity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didRediscoverRemoteEntity (entity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didUpdateRemoteEntity (entity: AVB17221Entity!, changedProperties changedProperties : AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didAddLocalEntity (newEntity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didRemoveLocalEntity(oldEntity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didRediscoverLocalEntity(entity: AVB17221Entity!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}

func didUpdateLocalEntity (entity: AVB17221Entity!, changedProperties changedProperties : AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged!, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}
```

Here is my class declaration:

```
class MainWindowController : NSObject, AVB17221EntityDiscoveryDelegate
```

And here is what the compiler is saying:

> Type 'MainWindowController' does not conform to protocol 'AVB17221EntityDiscoveryDelegate'

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Apple Developer forum:

Changed lines to:

```
func didUpdateRemoteEntity (entity: AVB17221Entity!, changedProperties : AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}
func didUpdateLocalEntity (entity: AVB17221Entity!, changedProperties : AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged, on17221EntityDiscovery entityDiscovery: AVB17221EntityDiscovery!){}
```

AVB17221EntityPropertyChanged is not a reference type, so you shouldn't make it optional.